# Does anyone know what the Fortigate SSL VPN error 6 on the linux client means?

Tags: ssl, vpn, fortigate

I often get:

`SSLVPN down unexpectedly with error:6`

When trying to connect the `64bit/forticlientsslvpn_cli`.  My experience has been:

1. Once you start getting, no number of retries will get you connected.
2. A machine reboot clears the error.

Just wondering if anyone knows what exactly error 6 is.  Since a reboot clear it, it would seem to just be some resource not being cleared/dumped.  And If I knew exactly what, I could probably clear that resource without having to resort to a reboot.

I am using `4.4.2307` of the Forti client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that simply updating to 4.4.2317 resolved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

SSLVPN down unexpectedly with error:6

I was facing the same issue and found out that someone was trying to connect to the VPN connection with the same user. Only one connection can be established at a time.